# What parts of default authorization template can I safaly delete?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, asp.net-authorization

I want to make the simplest authorization on my website including user roles. The default template is too complex for me. I don't need external login and other stuff. What are the core parts that my project should contain?

Comment: ASP.NET5? Or what version?

Comment: Yes, it's about ASP.NET 5

Answer (score 0):

I would not be intimidated by the new ASP.NET Identity membership system. Lots of good articles out there to explain how it works, and I would strongly recommend you get a basic understanding of it.

To get started, you can remove `VerifyCode, ExternalLoginFailure, ExternalLoginConfirmation, ExternalLoginCallback, SendCode, ExternalLogin`. You can also remove the AccountViewModels that corresponds to these methods, however leaving them will not hurt anything.

You probably want to keep `forgotpassword` and `resetpassword`.

I would recommend you create a new project, make sure registering and login works, then start removing stuff and see what breaks. Step through the debugger in the login and register methods to see what parts do what.